# A recursive function that always returns 91 given a natural number argument under 100

Tags: haskell, math, recursion

I was reading a book introducing formal verification algorithms with Haskell Discrete Mathematics with Haskell, and there I found a counter-example of inductively defined functions:

```
f91 :: Int -> Int
f91 x = if x > 100
        then x - 10
        else f91 . f91 $ x + 11
```

This recursive function is promised to return 91 if the argument ranges between 0 and 100: I hope somebody could explain to me how the algorithm of this recursive function works.

Comment: Why would you need a recursive function to do that?

Comment: Well you first keep incrementing until you reach `x > 100` and next you will alternate with -10 and +11 until you reach the fixed point: `91`...

Comment: I imagine there's a far easier, more straightforward solution to this. This seems convoluted.

Comment: Do you want us to solve your homework? ;-) Thats university 1st semester stuff.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis It's not I need such a function, I just read the code and was willing to understand it.

Comment: Assume you run with an input of `5`. On every recursion it will add `11` to it until it becomes `>100`. in this case it will be `5 + 9 * 11 = 104`. From that point on it will subtract `10` becoming `94`, then add `11` becoming `105` then `95`, `106`, `96`, `107`, `97`, `108`, `98`, `109`, `99`, `110`, `100`, `90`, `101`, `91`, bingo!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for the explanation, maybe it's my problem not to be able to understand the explanation, it seems rather obscure, why does 100 have to be the boundary number? and what if I change the value being subtracted or added by x? And finally how do I apply such a sort to other numbers?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Now I think I get it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [McCarthy 91 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McCarthy_91_function)?

Suppose you start with a value `x > 100`, then the result is simply `x - 10`, so a value from `91` onwards.

Now suppose the value is from `90` to `100`. Then `f91` takes the `else` branch and `x + 11` is between `101` and `111`. The first `f91` application brings all the value to the range `91 - 101`; only `101` satisfies the `then` branch of the second application of `f91`, and for that the result (`x - 10`) is `91`.

For all the other values we get the range `102 - 111` in the `else` branch. However the `else` branch applies `f91 . f91` to that value; since all the values are `> 100`, the first `f91` brings the values down to `92 - 101`, of which only `101` passes the condition `> 100` of the second `f91` and becomes `91`.

The rest of the values go through the same cycle until all become `91`. Suppose you have a different interval of `11` values below `100`. The `f91` first brings that interval above `100` and then keeps reducing the values to `91` starting from the higher end of the interval in the same manner. Please see the **proof** by induction linked in the wikipedia page.

Comment: This is a great answer, but it is also a link-only answer, which are against the SO policy, IIRC. You should expand it to integrate the main points of the linked-to page. http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: Forgot about that rule, thanks. It seems very odd to duplicate wiki, so I tried to add a bit of own insight without duplicating the linked info.

Comment: You are very welcome, hope I didn't mess anything up too much, the formal proof should probably explain the matter better